# structures and pointers error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

ok I have three structs:

```
struct rss_s {
    Radio_types device_type;  // Its device_type which is defined by the typedef above Radio_Types
    char * device_info;   // some thing about the radio NAV/COM/etc.
    char * device_model;      // the Manufactures part/model number.
    char * device_serial;     // the device's serial number..
    int power_48v;        // power to the unit..
    int power_400hz;
    int panel_lamps;      // turn off or on the Panel Lamps only
    void * radio_info;

    struct radio_s_C614L8
    {
        loopsw_614L8 loop_sw_614L8;  this is an emum
        modesw_614L8 mode_sw_614L8;  this is an emum
        int sw_band;
        int sw_bfo;
        int meter;
        tuner *Tuner;
        int tuners;
    };

    typedef struct tuner_s
    {
        char *device_name;      // OS NAME
        int frequency[tuned];
        int power;
        int dial_lamp;
        void * back_radio;      // back-link to radios[n]
        void * back_info;       // back-link to radio_xxxx
        int fd[];
    } tuner;
```

I initialize them in main.c

```
// Radio 614L8
static tuner tuner_C614L8[] = {{ .device_name = "/dev/TBD", }};
static struct radio_s_C614L8  radio_C614L8 = { .Tuner = &tuner_C614L8, .tuners =   DIM(tuner_C614L8) };

static struct rss_s radios[] = {
{ .device_type  = C614L8,
  .device_info  = "ADF",
  .device_model = "614L8",
  .device_serial = "8384",
  .radio_info = &radio_C614L8,},};
```

the above works with out errors....
but when I try to initialize the the above radio... in my init_C614L8.c
with the following code I get an error...
***error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type*** in lines 4 & 6

```
int init_C614L8( struct rss_s  * radios ){
int rw, i;
struct radio_s_614L8 * rad_info = radios -> radio_info;
tuner * this_tuner  = rad_info -> Tuner;
    // Now we will loop over the sub_devices....
for ( i = 0;  i < rad_info -> tuners; i++ ) {
```

I think I have to cast something but not shure
Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to post all these code? Include [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if I dont show you my code and the structures how are you going to make an intelligent comment.

Comment: I meant it's not short enough. Do you really need to post all the fields names such as `power_400hz` and `modesw_614L8`? Make a short program to reproduce the problem. Probably you can find the error while doing so.

Comment: Do you realize both `radio_s_C614L8` and `tuner_s`are *nested* in `rss_s`, which has no closing `}` in the code posted ? Properly indenting your posted code will show this:

Comment: Please do not post C code with spaces around the arrow `->` operator.  It is bad manners to abuse the syntax like that.  I know you've been asked before to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) when you create questions — I know, because I did the asking.  If we can't take the code in the question and run the compiler on it, it dramatically increases the difficulty of providing you with an answer.

Comment: sorry I missed the closing "}" of the rss_s structure. and about "paces around the arrow -> operator. It is bad manners to abuse the syntax like that." Please show me in K&R where that is!! spaces are optional there is NO rule of style in C maybe in ADA but NOT C.

Comment: and my question still stands I think my error is in casting

Comment: If I wish to use JFS C standard for safety of flight thats one thing but ANSI C... Please No Horses! lets just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `rss.h` you declare

```
struct radio_s_C614L8
```

but in `init_C614L8.c` you use

```
struct radio_s_614L8
```

which is declared nowhere.

**Update:**

To fix this error

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

In `init_C614L8.c` (and any other place, but `rss.h`) replace

```
struct radio_s_614L8
```

by

```
struct radio_s_C614L8
```

---

The lesson learned here is either go for some glasses or some sleep! ;-) And also: "The compiler never lies!"

Comment: If this solve you issue you might like to mark an answer so that SO shows the question as answered.

Comment: nope.. still there.. :( did you look at the code on my website?? Its on my web server: www.phoenixaerospace.us/tmp/NexGen/

Comment: @Phoenixcomm Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the definition of `struct radio_s_614L8` is not visible to the code where the errors are seen.  You have either forgotten to `include` the definition or there are `#if...` directives removing the definitions or `include`s you think are there.

Comment: all of my structure definitions are in rss.h and that is **#include "rss.h"** on every page of my code. and all of the initializations are done in the module main.c but above my main function. and no #if(s) in my code

Comment: @Phoenixcomm Well, that doesn't change the error.  The compiler is seeing `struct radio_s_614L8` as an incomplete type.  This means it doesn't know what's inside the `struct`. Whatever you did to provide it is not working. Unless you you post full code, there's nothing else that can be said.

Comment: oh well you want to see my code... Its on my web server: www.phoenixaerospace.us/tmp/NexGen/